# How to add bookmark on multiple images of word document using office js

Tags: reactjs, office-js, word-addins

I am creating one word add-in which will display image details in table and image in next page after clicking on particular image in DOM. I want to add hyperlink to every images of table. For adding hyperlink, I have to create bookmark on each and every images going to be insert. Here I have tried to get all the images of document and adding bookmark on that images.

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
      const pictures = context.document.body.inlinePictures;
      pictures.load()
      await context.sync();
      pictures?.items?.map((item)=>{
          console.log("items",item);
          let bookmarkName = "Bookmark" + new Date().getTime()
          const bookmarkObj = { "ImageId": item.altTextTitle, "bookmark": bookmarkName }
          console.log("data called");
          bookmarkArr.push(bookmarkObj)
          console.log("bookmarkArr", bookmarkArr);
    
          localStorage.setItem('bookmark', JSON.stringify(bookmarkArr))
          item.insertBookmark(bookmarkName)
          
      })
    })
```

here, it is giving type error for insertBookmark() and saying that insertBookmark() is not a function. I have to inform you that If I am adding bookmark for single image, it is working fine but when I tried for multiple images it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `item` variable is type [InlinePicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.inlinepicture). This type does not have an `insertBookmark` method.